# AVPlayer cannot play cached songs after app update. Why?

Tags: ios, app-store, avplayer

My app caches songs from music service for offline playback. They are saved into a subdirectory under `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)`. I also have code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` routine to verify that cached files are still there and validates the `NSDictionary` which maps track Ids to their local path.

I haven't experienced any issues with, but upon rollout of updated version through AppStore - `AVPlayer` stopped playing these cached songs. Following I've checked:

- Downloaded songs are still there in Cache folder
- No errors in the log
- App doesn't crash
- On the UI I see them marked as cached which means the "cleanup" routine found them on device
- Non-cached songs play fine
- Newly cached songs play fine as well

What could possibly be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me long time to figure out, but basically: app GUIDs change upon iOS app updates and I had full path stored in my dictionary of cached songs!